# Changing root directory in apache2 is giving 403 Forbidden error

Tags: apache, ubuntu, configuration

Though there are many similar questions here but I could not fix my problem from them.
I have installed `Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)` in my `ubuntu(14.04)`. I have changed two configuration files to change the default `DocumentRoot` of `apache` which is `/var/www`
to `/home/name/www`. The files I have changed are `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf`. In `apache2.conf` I put

```
<Directory /home/name/www>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and in `000-default.conf` I changed,

```
DocumentRoot /home/name/www
```

My `/home/name/www` file has necessary permissions.

`drwxr-xr-x  3 www-data www-data   www`

But when I try to access `localhost` from browser I receive 
`You don't have permission to access / on this server.` error. What have i missed?

Comment: Did you reload apache? `sudo service apache2 restart`

Comment: @Fernando yes but there were also some other changes. I forgot to put my solution in answer. I'll put it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing the default root directory of `apache` from `/var/www` to `/home/<username>/www` following changes worked for me.
I edited the following values of  **etc/apache2/apache2.conf** file like this. Before editing the file it's a good practice to keep a backup of the original.

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /home/<username>/www>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then I changed  **/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf** file's `DocumentRoot`.

```
DocumentRoot /home/<username>/www
```

After that restart the apache server,

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Did the same exact thing on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache 2.4.7, doesn't work: Forbidden access